# Count the number of distinct strings and their occurrence in a variable

Tags: stata

I have a variable called `Category` that specifies the category of observations. The problem is that some observation have multiple categories. For example:

```
 id     Category
  1     Economics
  2     Biology
  3     Psychology; Economics
  4     Economics; Psychology
```

There is no meaning in the order of categories. They are always separated by ";". There are 250 categories, so creating dummy variables might be tricky. I have the complete list of categories in a separate Excel file if this might help.

What I want is simply to summarize my dataset by unique categories such as Economics (3), Psychology (2), Biology (1) (so the sum of all can be superior to the number of observations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabsplit` from the `tab_chi` package on SSC will do this for you.

```
clear 
input id str42 Category
  1     "Economics"
  2     "Biology"
  3     "Psychology; Economics"
  4     "Economics; Psychology"
 end 

capture ssc install tab_chi 

tabsplit Category, p(;) 

   Category |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
    Biology |          1       16.67       16.67
  Economics |          3       50.00       66.67
 Psychology |          2       33.33      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |          6      100.00
```

Note: You can count semi-colons and thus phrases like this.

```
gen count = 1 + length(category) - length(subinstr(category, ";", "", .))
```

The logic is that you measure the length of the string and its length should semi-colons `;` be replaced by empty strings (namely, removed). The difference is the number of semi-colons, to which you add 1.

EDIT: How to get to a different data structure, starting with the data example above.

```
.  split Category, p(;) 
variables created as string: 
Category1  Category2

.  drop Category 

.  reshape long Category, i(id) j(mention) 
(note: j = 1 2)

Data                               wide   ->   long
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of obs.                        4   ->       8
Number of variables                   3   ->       3
j variable (2 values)                     ->   mention
xij variables:
                    Category1 Category2   ->   Category
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

.  drop if missing(Category) 
(2 observations deleted)

.  list, sepby(id) 

     +----------------------------+
     | id   mention      Category |
     |----------------------------|
  1. |  1         1     Economics |
     |----------------------------|
  2. |  2         1       Biology |
     |----------------------------|
  3. |  3         1    Psychology |
  4. |  3         2     Economics |
     |----------------------------|
  5. |  4         1     Economics |
  6. |  4         2    Psychology |
     +----------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly. This package will certainly be useful. 

A little problem maybe is that the tabsplit command does not accept 'by sort'. Any idea how I could proceed if I wanted to apply tabsplit to sub group ?

Comment: See revised answer. Wanting to do this repeatedly is a clear indication that you need a different version of the dataset as well as the present.